# image's opacity is not getting decreased behind the pre-loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
< script > $(window).load(function() {
  $("#loading-center").click(function() {
    $("#loading").fadeOut(500);
  })
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $("#loading").fadeOut(7000);
}) < /script>
```

```css
.demo-3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px
}
.demo-3 figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -50px
}
.demo-3 figure img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: -15px 0
}
.demo-3 figure figcaption {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.demo-3 figure h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left
}
.demo-3 figure p {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left
}
.demo-3 figure figcaption {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 29px 44px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 76, 110, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s
}
.demo-3 figure img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s
}
.demo-3 figure:hover img,
figure.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
.demo-3 figure:hover figcaption,
figure.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0)
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <div id="loading-center">
    <div id="loading-center-absolute">
      <div id="object"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<ul class="demo-3">
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="D:\\ps\Notepad++\game.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="width:100%;">
      <figcaption>
        <h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the java script is for the pre-loading screen and the css is for the image. when the page is loading everything is faded inside the pre-loading screen but the image is not faded . before adding the animation in the image the pre-loading screen worked fine but after adding the animation the image's opacity does not decrease as shown in the image. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)[image: this is the image of the problem.]

Comment: don't use a space between the "<" and the element name

Comment: Just delete unnecessary code to Look Post simple and help-able

Comment: there is no unnecessary code all the demo-3 class are for animation if i remove that the image gets faded but with them the image creates problem